# debugging a chrome extension in real time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a fork of an open source browser extension, but I've never really worked with extensions and have minimal experience with javascript so I'm struggling to understand some of it. I was wondering if there's any way to step through the program, interpreting and watching it execute line by line, like you would for example a python program in IDLE, just to see how it functions on a basic level.

Comment: Yes, use the built-in **devtools debugger**, there are many tutorials. See also [How to open the correct devtools console to see output from an extension script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)